# Creating a Spring bean holds ServletRequest properties

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I need to create a Spring bean so that it stores `serverName`, `serverPort`, `contextPath` properties of a HttpServletRequest object so that I can inject this bean to other beans as I need.

In my opinion, those properties do not change with any URI so that it is good to  initialize this once (anyway, passing `request` instance many times is not so expensive at all).

The problem is, how can I inject `HttpServletRequest` instance to my configuration bean? I prefer xml based injection. Most probably we need to inject it as a `<property>` but I do not know what will be `name` or `ref` for this `ServletRequest` object.

The aim is to hold those variables in a bean so that they will be accessible from any bean and I won't need to pass `request` object to many methods as an argument when I need to obtain `serverName` etc.

Any ideas how to create such a bean and its configuration?

Comment: I think this is a bad idea.  Why should layers outside of the web tier need to know these things?  Feels like you're letting web information leak into the rest of your app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using a [request-scoped bean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-request), and autowiring the current request into your bean:

```
public class RequestHolder {
   private @Autowired HttpServletRequest request;

   public String getServerName() {
      return request.getServerName();
   }
}
```

And then in the XML:

```
<bean id="requestHolder" class="com.x.RequestHolder" scope="request">
  <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

You can then wire the `requestHolder` bean into wheiever business logic bean you choose.

Note the `<aop:scoped-proxy/>` - this is the easiest way of injecting a request-scoped bean into a singleton - see [Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection) for how this works, and how to configure the `aop` namespace.