# Spring Security - retrieve user IP, browser info and requested page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

We use `RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter` as to implement pre-authentication strategy and `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider` as the authentication provider. One of the requirements is to store all successful logins to the database with following information. As user IP address and other request related info is not available in `UserDetailsService` class, what is the best strategy to retrieve this info and store in db?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

All the information is available through `HttpServletRequest`. You can obtain it by:

#### Dependency injection

The easiest way would be to inject servlet request directly into your `UserDetailsService:` class:

```
public MyDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

  @Autowired
  private HttpServletRequest request;

  //...

}
```

*(as suggested by OP)* Remember to add the following listener to your `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

UPDATE: This works because Spring injects special scoped proxy implementing `HttpServletRequest`, so you are able to access request-scoped request "bean" from singleton-scoped `MyDetailsService`. Under the hood every call to `request`'s parameters is routed to `org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder#requestAttributesHolder` `ThreadLocal` which you can also access directly. As you can see Spring is very flexible when it comes to scoping rules. It just works.

#### `RequestContextHolder`

Another approach is to use [`RequestContextHolder`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html):

```
HttpServletRequest request = 
  ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.
    currentRequestAttributes()).
    getRequest();
```

#### Further reading:

- [Creating a Spring bean holds ServletRequest properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514883)
- [Spring: how do I inject an HttpServletRequest into a request-scoped bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320674)

Comment: thanks for the reply Tomasz, I haven't tried your solution yet but one question.. Isn't custom UserDetailsService a sesion-scoped bean? I thought an object of this type gets created only when there is a new session or the existing session expires. If it is indeed a session-scoped bean then how can we inject HttpServletRequest which is a request-scoped? If UserDetailsService is request based then how is that call to the loadUser..() method is not made for every request?

Comment: @Tomasz, would this work? Is UserDetailsService typically a request-scoped bean?

Comment: *@rrkwells*, *@Peter Mularien*: `UserDetailsService ` should always be a singleton and `HttpServletRequest` is request scoped. This works thanks to extra Spring `scoped-proxy` magic applied transparently. Also see my update. Don't worry and just try it :-).

Comment: @Tomasz.. sorry for not replying earlier.. I just tested your first solution today and it is working as expected. I just had to add the request context listener in the web.xml file. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help, I added `RequestContextListener` to my answer to be complete, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This might be a good approach:

1) Create a class that extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler

```
public class MyCustomSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
```

2) Assign the "success handler" to your security filter:

```
<beans:bean id="myFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureHandler" />
               <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandler" />
    </beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="successHandler" class="yourPackage.MyCustomSuccessHandler" >
        <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/index.html" /> 
        <beans:property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="true"/> 
    </beans:bean>
```