# spring security - access request parameters inside UserDetailsService implementation

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm working on a java spring mvc application. I have implemented the `UserDetailsService` interface like this:

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class SecurityDAO implements UserDetailsService{

     @Override
     public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
         ...
     }

     ....
}
```

I need to find the user login url inside `loadUserByUsername` method(because the project has multiple login urls). In fact, **I want to access request parameters inside `UserDetailsService` implementation.**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just inject the request on your service:

```
 @Autowired
 private HttpServletRequest request;
```

For it to work you need to register RequestContextListener previously, though:

```
@Bean 
public RequestContextListener requestContextListener(){
    return new RequestContextListener();
}
```

Comment: Cause `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request...`

Comment: You didn't declared the `RequestContextListener`. Are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: No, I don't use spring boot. I declared `RequestContextListener` in my `SecurityConfig` class.

Comment: Do you happen to be using web.xml as well?

Comment: I have `web.xml` in my project. But it only has `<session-timeout>` tag.

Comment: In this case add a new listener with `<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>` instead.

Answer (score 8):

All the information is available through `HttpServletRequest`. You can obtain it by:

#### Dependency injection

The easiest way would be to inject servlet request directly into your `UserDetailsService:` class:

```
public MyDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

  @Autowired
  private HttpServletRequest request;

  //...

}
```

or

```
public MyDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

  @Autowired
  private HttpServletRequest request;

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username){
                HttpServletRequest request  =
             ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())
                    .getRequest();
    }

}
```

Remember to add the following listener to your `web.xml` if you are not spring boot:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

If you are using spring boot, add below this.

```
@Bean 
public RequestContextListener requestContextListener(){
    return new RequestContextListener();
}
```

UPDATE: This works because Spring injects special scoped proxy implementing `HttpServletRequest`, so you are able to access request-scoped request "bean" from singleton-scoped `MyDetailsService`. Under the hood every call to `request`'s parameters is routed to `org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder#requestAttributesHolder` `ThreadLocal` which you can also access directly. As you can see Spring is very flexible when it comes to scoping rules. It just works.

#### `RequestContextHolder`

Another approach is to use [`RequestContextHolder`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html):

```
HttpServletRequest request = 
  ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.
    currentRequestAttributes()).
    getRequest();
```

#### Further reading:

- [Creating a Spring bean holds ServletRequest properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514883)
- [Spring: how do I inject an HttpServletRequest into a request-scoped bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320674)

Answer (score 4):

Simple way:
1) register RequestContextListener

```
@Bean
public RequestContextListener requestContextListener(){
return new RequestContextListener();
}
```

2) And to main class:

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.
currentRequestAttributes()).
getRequest();
```

3) After that we can take params in custom headers:

```
request.getHeader("OrganizationId")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current request with

```
HttpServletRequest request  =
 ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())
        .getRequest();
```

ans then access the request params from there.